# Advice - How to view assembly code or debug into DLL or what's being loaded?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, dll

I am not sure how to pose this question, but basically I want more information on the following error and want to know what these assemblies contain.  I am using VS 2008 and Silverlight 3 and basically I have 2 SL projects, with one referencing the other for a resource.  I know the file is there, but don't know why I am getting the error.  Is there any way to debug into so I can what it is there or expecting?  Is there some tool that can view assemblies?

```
   Attribute    /MyAssemblyDll;component/path/Test1.xaml    value is out of range. [Line: 13    Position: 28]  
--- Inner Exception    --- The given key was not present in the dictionary.
```